# Apache vHost catch all configuration

Tags: apache, virtualhost

idea is, to have a vHost configuration for specific ServerNames (Aliases) but don't allow to access the website via the IP-Address.

Therefore I have used the site-configuration delivered with apache 000-default.conf to catch access via the ip-address and created a separate conf-file with the configruation valid for the domains.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  DocumentRoot /var/www/html

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

  <Directory /var/www/html/>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

/var/www/html/index.html will show some error message.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com int.example.com
  
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

  LogLevel info

  RewriteEngine on

  Alias "/.well-known" "/var/www/letsencrypt/.well-known/"
  Alias "/ErrorPages" "/var/www/html/"
  Alias "/" "/var/www/html/website/"

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

  <Directory /var/www/html/website/>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>

  <Directory "/var/www/letsencrypt/.well-known">
    Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  ErrorDocument 503 /error_503.html
  ErrorDocument 404 /error_404.html
  ErrorDocument 500 /error_500.html

</VirtualHost>
```

If "000-default.conf" is not activated, access works via the domain, but also via the IP-Address.
If "000-default.conf" is activated, I always get the message from /var/www/html/index.html, regardless if only the IP-address is used or one of the domains configured.

Where is my wrong expectation?